# How to set different HDRI for different objects as IBL?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri

I have multiple objects in the scene and want them to receive different HDRI lighting. To my knowledge, the HDRI environment is a world property. It would affect each object equally. But I would like to ask if there is a solution for objects to receive different HDRI lighting.

My goal is to augment the autonomous driving image data and add objects that do not exist in the original image using blender. This requires me to set different lighting depending on where the object is inserted.

For example, I want to add 2 vehicles to the scene (more than 2 in more cases.). One of them will be in shadow and use a darker HDRI, while another will be out of shadow and use a brighter HDRI. However, currently, I can just use the same HDRI for these two vehicles.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: HDRI lighting is not a good solution for this case. If you want shadows to affect objects in the scene, you need those shadows in your scene. This means you need to recreate at least rough shapes of the objects and lighting in the environment. It's possible to create lighting with different mesh spheres around different objects and textured emission shaders. You could turn off camera visibility for those spheres, but that will not produce good results and will have a lot of problems. Like what happens at the borders or when objects move between different lighting areas?..

Answer (score 0):

Just add some geometry that will cast that shadow in the place of house visible on hdri.